# How to set login page as start page in MVC Core 2 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using MVC Core 2.0 and Visual studio 2017. When I run the program, I would like to show login page (Account\Login) instead of home page (HOME\Index). I change the route config as below but no luck.

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: When you create a .Net Core project from Visual Studio, you usually need to, in the solution explorer, right click in the project and take a look at the properties...you need to set it there too....if you where using VSCode instead, changing the route just like you did, should give you the desired result(I tested it with vscode and changin the default route works as expected)